# Is there a beter way to handle response from async call instead of doing setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using javascript async await to make a service call to the server, mostly from componentDidMount or componentDidUpdate, but when I want to send the response as props to other components, I am currently updating the state of the component with the response. But since as the user I dont actually modify that particular state, it kinda feels like a wasted variable. Is there any way to get it as props to my component instead of setting the state.

```
class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {data: {}}
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        const {data} = await getService();
        this.setState({data})
    }
    render(){
       return (<ChildComponent data/>)
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get the data which is a property from response as props instead of setting it as state and retrieving it from state

Comment: Have a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html But there is a good chance that using properties is the "right" way to do it.

Comment: That looks fine to me, and you actualy modifie that state, it goes from `data={}` to `data=someNewValueThatYouGetFromService`;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your example is a scaled down version of your actual app, I would say what you are doing is fine.  Otherwise, I would have a minor query around why not have ChildComponent do they fetching for data to avoid 'prop drilling' i.e. passing props through multiple layers of components to eventually reach a component that cares about the data.

Answer (score 0):

It's not fine to make an async call in `componentDidMount`because whenever the state is changed, the `componentDidMount` is called ==> there is a lot of call to the service.

there is a more elegant way to do it, using Redux(state management tool which contains the state of the application), by doing @async(make here all your call services and automatically are connected to other component without passing it in props)